# Describing a particular scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I want to describe the affine scheme $Spec(\mathbb{C}(t) \otimes_\mathbb{C} \mathbb{C}(t))$. My task is to especially show that this scheme as infinetly many points, but I'm more interested in how to approach this in general. I'm not familiar in working with schemes, so I would be thankful for someone illustrating the approach to me, or to point me in the right direction. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: By $\Bbb C(t)$, I assume you mean the field of rational functions in one variable. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: $\mathbb{C}(t) \otimes_\mathbb{C} \mathbb{C}(t)$ is a subring of $\Bbb C(s, t)$. can you tell which subring?

Comment: I dont think I can, why is it not the whole $\mathbb{C}(s,t)$? That would be the case for the polynomial rings

Comment: Well, $\frac1{s+t}$ is not part of this subring, for instance. But $\frac1s, \frac1t$ and $\frac1{st}$ are, as is any pure polynomial in $s$ and $t$.

Comment: Ah I see, then I get which subring it is, I'm not sure how to write it down mathematically though

Comment: "The subring consisting of finite sums of elements of the form $f(s)g(t)$" is one way.

Comment: So would the next step be to identify the maximal ideals in this subring of $\mathbb{C}(s,t)$?

Comment: Just finding an infinite family of primes is enough. That is, after all, what $\operatorname{Spec}$ is all about.

Comment: And how do I go about that? Just eyeball one or is there a particular one standing out?

Comment: I would think that $s+at$ for different $a$ would be enough. You'd have to check that, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For clarity I'll write $A=\mathbb C(s)\otimes_\mathbb C \mathbb C(t)$ and then describe the scheme $X=\operatorname {Spec}A$.
The trick is to realise that $\mathbb C(s)$ is the fraction field $\mathbb C(s)=S^{-1}\mathbb C[s]$ where $S=\mathbb C[s]\setminus \{0\}$ and similarly $\mathbb C(t)=T^{-1}\mathbb C[t]$ with $T=\mathbb C[t]\setminus \{0\}$. 
We then have: $$A=\mathbb C(s)\otimes_\mathbb C \mathbb C(t)=S^{-1}\mathbb C[s]\otimes_\mathbb C S^{-1}\mathbb C[t]=(ST)^{-1}(\mathbb C[s]\otimes_\mathbb C \mathbb C[t])=(ST)^{-1}\mathbb C[s,t]$$ 
Hence $A$ consists of rational functions of the form $$\phi(s,t)=\frac {P(s,t)}{q(s)r(t)} \quad \operatorname {with} \quad P(s,t)\in \mathbb C[s,t], \:q(s)\in \mathbb C[s]\setminus \{0\}, \: r(t)\in \mathbb C[t] \setminus \{0\}$$ 
The points of the scheme $X=\operatorname {Spec}A$ then consists of the prime ideals  $\mathfrak p\subset \mathbb C[s,t]$ disjoint from $ST$, i.e. containing no $q(s)\neq 0$ and no $r(t)\neq 0$.
So, finally it is easy to describe the scheme $X$ but the result is rather  strange:

**The scheme $X$ is obtained from the affine plane $\mathbb A^2_\mathbb C$ by deleting all its closed points $\langle s-a,t-b\rangle $, all generic points $\langle s-a\rangle $ of the "vertical" lines $s-a=0$ and all generic points $\langle t-b\rangle $ of the "horizontal" lines $t-b=0$**.
**Thus $X$ consists of the generic point $\langle 0\rangle $ and the generic points $\langle f(s,t)\rangle $of all irreducible curves $f(s,t)=0$ which are neither  a "horizontal" nor a "vertical" line.**

In particular notice that the Krull dimension of $X$ is $1$.
That $X$ is obtained from $\mathbb A^2_\mathbb C$ after one has removed all its classical points reminds me of the [Cheshire-Cat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEAysdnvW-0) in *Alice in Wonderland* whose grin remains after he disappears...